# Как слить два xml документа по атрибутам?

Tags: c#, xml

**Документ 1:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<node t="Type1" n="8" v="61">
    <node t="Type31" n="79" v="3"></node>
</node>
<node t="Type2" n="4" v="12"></node>
</root>
```

**Документ 2:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<node t="Type1" n="8" v="61">
   <node t="Type7" n="54" v="449"></node>
</node>
</root>
```

**После объединения хочется видеть такой результат:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<node t="Type1" n="8" v="61">
        <node t="Type31" n="79" v="3"></node>
        <node t="Type7" n="54" v="449"></node>
</node>
<node t="Type2" n="4" v="12"></node>
</root>
```

Comment: Тут возможны варианты: 1)xslt-запрос 2) 2*XmlReader -> XmlWriter 3) Импотрт в массив - обьединить - экспорт в xml.

Comment: А что делать, если разный порядок? Например, в первом документе `<Root><a/><b/></Root>`, во втором `<Root><b/><a/></Root>`. Какой должен быть результат?

Comment: я использую эту разметку для отображения в TreeView. XML документ отображает маршрут объекта. Таких маршрутов множество. Есть необходимость слить все эти маршруты в один, для отображения полной карты. Порядок полагаю должен оставаться относительно первого из двух обрабатываемых древ.

Comment: что используете для работы с XML, не текстовом же виде вы их в TreeView выгружаете?

Comment: я использую XmlNode

Answer (score 1):

С `XmlNode` работать не слишком удобно, поэтому рискну предложить вариант вариант с использованием LiNQtoXML.

Нам потребуется метод для сравнения двух элементов с учетом атрибутов. Из имеющегося: `Equals()` - не подходит, выполняет сравнение ссылок; `XNode.DeepEquals` - не подходит, требует полного равенства элементов, включая их содержимое. А также метод слияния. Решение предложенное Microsoft (**[тык](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/kb/311530#bookmark-6c)**) не дало нужных результатов.

Ок, строим свое решение (предложения по оптимизации приветствуются).

Для удобства дальнейшего использования, реализуем в виде методов расширения к классу `XElement`:

```
public static class XMergeExtensions
{       
    public static bool XEquals(this XElement element, XElement other)
    {
        bool result = false;
        if (result = element.Name == other.Name)
        {
            foreach (var attr in element.Attributes())
            {
                result &= other.Attribute(attr.Name)?.Value == attr.Value;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    public static void XMerge(this XElement element, XElement other)
    {
        foreach (var el in other.Elements())
        {
            var temp = element.Elements().FirstOrDefault(e => e.XEquals(el));
            if (temp != null)
            {
                temp.XMerge(el);
            }
            else if (el.HasElements)
            {
                var newEl = new XElement(el.Name, el.Attributes());
                newEl.XMerge(el);
                element.Add(newEl);
            }
            else
            {
                element.Add(el);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Данный подход гарантирует уникальность дочерних элементов с одинаковым набором атрибутов на каждом уровне вложения.

Дальнейшее использование:

```
var doc1 = XDocument.Load("doc1.xml");
var doc2 = XDocument.Load("doc2.xml");
XElement mergedDoc = new XElement("root");
mergedDoc.XMerge(doc1.Root);
mergedDoc.XMerge(doc2.Root);
new XDocument(doc1.Declaration, mergedDoc).Save("mergedDoc.xml");
```